# How can I (re-)enable ssh in chromeos?

Tags: ssh, chromebook

Recently I got a chromebook. I installed the ssh app and used it once. As far as I know, I didn't do anything to disable the app.

Later I tried to use the ssh app again. When I click on the corresponding icon, a tab opens and disappears too quickly to see anything on it. Going back to the [app's install page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo)  shows a message:

> This item has been disabled in Chrome. **Enable this item**.

("Enable this item" is a link.)

Clicking the link to enable the program briefly blanks the tab and then returns to the same page, with the message still in place.

After learning about crosh, I opened a tab for it. Entering ssh as a command returns this message:

> The 'ssh' command has been removed.  Please install the official SSH extension:
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo

which just puts me into an endless circle of what I've mentioned above.

How can I re-enable the ssh app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andrew M.'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1240131/18886) suggests, I uninstalled the ssh app and re-installed it. Unfortunately, I had the same problem - after one use, it wouldn't allow me to re-start the app. Among a few other things I tried, I started the app with nothing else running in the Chrome browser (in fact, the browser was not running, prior to that, I had the browser up with other tabs/sites active). That allowed the ssh app to start.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Secure Shell app from Chrome menu/More Tools/Extensions then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I can install and run it on my N22 still running Chrome OS 59 (checked for updates to 60 here in Germany, still not available). I couldn't find any hints on Google during the past month/year nor can I find hints in the rating of this addon, I'd recommend to reset the device and check if that has any effect. Not the most efficient solution, I know, but nobody else seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would just CTrl+alt+t and use Terminal shell if you cant get SSH app to work. Terminal is just a shell as well. I  prefer it over SSH anyday.. im trying to config SSH now to set up my server.

Comment: But, if ssh doesn't work, ssh doesn't work.  Running it from a terminal is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: Very true... Seems to be the issue I'm having.. I need a virtualbox something bad.. I was going to break down and get appache and can't get my SSH to cooperate it's like it's in a frozen status. May have to just dual boot my Chromebook and run Linux and OS temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but there a simple solution to it, simply go to the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) and launch the app from there.